# Should mutexes be used to ensure concurrency, while using POSIX message queues?

Tags: mutex

I am using a single POSIX message queue in my application which is accessed by multiple readers. Should I use mutexes in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [Is msgsnd() thread- and/or process-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158902/is-msgsnd-thread-and-or-process-safe) .
The short answer is - it's already thread-safe, so there's no need to use mutexes.